# Yii CJuiAutoComplete dynamic sourceUrl. How to?

Tags: php, yii, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Situation:

form with 'Country' dropdown, 'PostalCode' textfield, 'City' textfield.

Country dropdown has two items: Belgium and France (with there countrycode as effective value, respectively BE and FR)

The 'PostalCode' field is a CJuiAutoComplete field and depending on the value selected from the country dropdown, it either has to get the autocomplete data from 'BeCity/getBelgianPostalCodes' or 'FrCity/getFrenchPostalCodes'.

These two actions, independently from each other, work perfectly, they yield the correct autocomplete data. However, I cannot figure it out how to make it work dynamically based on the selected value of the country dropdown. I've tried putting the selected country in a session state, and generate the sourceUrl dynamically from there. When I look into the source of the generated html the generated sourceUrl is correct according to the selected country, but I still get the values from the first country that was loaded. So presumably there's a caching issue or something ?

Here is the code:

Form:

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Country'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,
                        'CountryCode',
                        CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('Visible'=>1)),'Code','Name'),
                        array('ajax'=>array(
                              'type'=>'POST',
                              'url'=>CController::createUrl('request/setRequestCountryCode'),
                              'data'=>'js:{CountryCode: $(this).val()}'))
                        ); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'CountryCode'); ?>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'PostalCode'); ?>
        <?php 

                $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                'name'=>'Request_PostalCode',
                'value'=>$model->PostalCode,
//                'source'=>$this->createUrl('BeCity/GetBelgianPostalCodes'),
                'sourceUrl'=>$this->createUrl(RequestController::actionGetPostalCodeAction()),
                'options'=>array(
                        'minLength'=>'1',
                        'showAnim'=>'fold',
                        'cache'=>'false',
                        'select'=> 'js:function(event, ui)
                            {
                                $("#Request_PostalCode").val(ui.item.value);
                                $("#Request_City").val(ui.item.city);
                                return false;
                            }'

                )
                ));

                ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'PostalCode'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'City'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'City',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>250)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'City'); ?>
    </div>
```

RequestController:

```
    public static function actionSetRequestCountryCode()
        {
            $countryCode = $_POST['CountryCode'];
            Yii::app()->user->setState('RequestCountryCode',$countryCode);
        }

        public static function actionGetPostalCodeAction()
        {
            $countryCode = Yii::app()->user->getState('RequestCountryCode');

            if($countryCode == 'BE')
                return 'BeCity/GetBelgianPostalCodes';
            elseif($countryCode == 'FR')
                return 'FrCity/GetFrenchPostalCodes';
            else
                return '';
        }
```

BeCity Controller:

```
public function actionGetBelgianPostalCodes()
        {                     
            $res =array();

            if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
                    // http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/database.dao
                    $qtxt ="SELECT
                            DISTINCT
                            CONCAT(bc.PostalCode, ' - ', bc.NameNL) as label,
                            bc.PostalCode as value,
                            bc.NameNL as city
                            FROM be_city bc
                            WHERE bc.PostalCode LIKE :qterm
                            ORDER BY bc.PostalCode, bc.NameNL ASC";
                    $command =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($qtxt);
                    $command->bindValue(":qterm", $_GET['term'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $res = $command->queryAll();
            }

            echo CJSON::encode($res);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
```

FrCity Controller:

```
public function actionGetFrenchPostalCodes()
        {                     
            $res =array();

            if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
                    // http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/database.dao
                    $qtxt ="SELECT
                            DISTINCT
                            CONCAT(fc.PostalCode, ' - ' , fc.NameFR) AS label,
                            fc.PostalCode as value,
                            fc.NameFR as city
                            FROM fr_city fc
                            WHERE fc.PostalCode LIKE :qterm
                            ORDER BY fc.PostalCode ASC, fc.NameFR ASC";
                    $command =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($qtxt);
                    $command->bindValue(":qterm", $_GET['term'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $res =$command->queryAll();
            }

            echo CJSON::encode($res);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
```

Is it the correct way to go with a session variable, or are there better ways to do it ?

And how about the caching issue ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Ok, was able to get it to work by having one action (function) taking the country parameter, and doing all the logic in that one action, instead of trying to reroute to two separate actions:

Form:

```
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Country'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,
                        'CountryCode',
                        CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('Visible'=>1)),'Code','Name')

                        ); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'CountryCode'); ?>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'PostalCode'); ?>
        <?php 

                $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                'name'=>'Request_PostalCode',
                'value'=>$model->PostalCode,
                'source'=>'js: function(request, response) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "'.$this->createUrl('Request/GetPostalCodes').'",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: {
                                        term: request.term,
                                        countryCode: $("#Request_CountryCode").val()
                                    },
                                    success: function (data) {
                                            response(data);
                                    }
                                })
                             }',
                'options'=>array(
                        'minLength'=>'1',
                        'showAnim'=>'fold',
                        'select'=> 'js:function(event, ui)
                            {
                                $("#Request_PostalCode").val(ui.item.value);
                                $("#Request_City").val(ui.item.city);
                                return false;
                            }'

                )
                ));

                ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'PostalCode'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'City'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'City',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>250)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'City'); ?>
    </div>
```

RequestController:

public function actionGetPostalCodes()
    {

```
    $countryCode = $_GET['countryCode'];

    $res =array();

    if (isset($_GET['term'])) 
    {

        $qtxt = '';

        if($countryCode == 'BE')
            $qtxt ="SELECT
                    DISTINCT
                    CONCAT(bc.PostalCode, ' - ', bc.NameNL) as label,
                    bc.PostalCode as value,
                    bc.NameNL as city
                    FROM be_city bc
                    WHERE bc.PostalCode LIKE :qterm
                    ORDER BY bc.PostalCode, bc.NameNL ASC";

        elseif($countryCode == 'FR')
            $qtxt ="SELECT
                    DISTINCT
                    CONCAT(fc.PostalCode, ' - ' , fc.NameFR) AS label,
                    fc.PostalCode as value,
                    fc.NameFR as city
                    FROM fr_city fc
                    WHERE fc.PostalCode LIKE :qterm
                    ORDER BY fc.PostalCode ASC, fc.NameFR ASC";

        if($qtxt != '')
        {
            $command =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($qtxt);
            $command->bindValue(":qterm", $_GET['term'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $res = $command->queryAll();
        }
    }

    echo CJSON::encode($res);
    Yii::app()->end();

}
```